# React | Component not showing updated state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to refresh a react component state based on the props.

I have this file which is the main a child component for a screen:

**RoomsList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import {connect} from "react-redux";

import {getRooms} from "../../store/actions";
import RoomIcon from "../RoomIcon/RoomIcon";

class RoomList extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onGetRooms();
    }

    renderRooms() {
        return this.props.rooms.map(room => {
            return (
                <RoomIcon key={room.id} room={room} />
            )
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                { this.props.rooms.length ? this.renderRooms() : <ActivityIndicator /> }
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
    }
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        rooms: state.rooms.rooms
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onGetRooms: () => dispatch(getRooms())
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RoomList);
```

**Rooms Reducer**

```
import { SET_ROOMS } from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    rooms: []
};

const roomsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_ROOMS:
            return {
                ...state,
                rooms: action.rooms
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default roomsReducer;
```

When the state is getting updated within the `mapStateToProps` function, which I can confirm it is doing as I put a console log inside of there to get the rooms and the object is the updated object.

However, it appears the the render isn't actually getting updated although the state is getting updated. I have tried to do a `componentWillReceiveProps` and assign the state but the state is never actually updated within here.

**Rooms Action**

```
import {SET_ROOMS} from './actionTypes';
import store from "../index";

export const getRooms = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch("http://localhost/rooms").catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        }).then(res => {
            res.json();
        }).then(parsedRes => {
            dispatch(setRooms(parsedRes));
        })
    }
};

export const addRoom = (roomName, roomDescription) => {
    const rooms = store.getState().rooms.rooms;

    const room = {
        room_name: roomName,
        room_description: roomDescription
    };

    return dispatch => {
        fetch("http://localhost/rooms", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(room)
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(parsedRes => {
            rooms.push(parsedRes);

            dispatch(setRooms(rooms));
        })
    }
};

export const setRooms = rooms => {
    return {
        type: SET_ROOMS,
        rooms: rooms
    }
};
```

**Initialising Redux Store**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';

const composeEnhancers = compose;

const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

export default store;
```

**Initializing Reducers**

```
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
import lightsReducer from "./lights";
import roomsReducer from "./rooms";
import modalsReducer from "./modals";

export default combineReducers({
    lights: lightsReducer,
    rooms: roomsReducer,
    modals: modalsReducer
});
```

Comment: When you log props what do you get?

Comment: Hi @Colin if you’re referring to inside of the mapStateToProps method and console logging inside of there I get the newly updated object with the added room object

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. I mean in `render` when you log what do you get?

Comment: Inside of the render, I only get the initial props. If I log, that console log is never actually called again

Comment: @Colin so inside of the mapStateToProps function I do a console log. In there, I can see the state updating when I actually add a new room. However, this doesn't seem to be reflecting on the actual component. I have tried to log out all of the data inside of the render method but nothing seems to happen. I map through without passing to a child component and still the state of the component doesn't seem to reflex what's actually happening with the redux state.

Comment: your code seems ok, so my guess is the reducer is doing something wrong. can you share the code of the reducer ?

Comment: Hi @AshKander I have updated the post to include the reducer

Comment: The reducer seems to be fine too. Can you show the code of the getRooms function? I see that your reducer only handles the SET_ROOMS action type. Is this the type returned by getRooms?

Comment: Hi @NielsLadekarl I have put this in now, sorry. I probably should have put all of these in the first place!

Comment: @tallent123 the action also seems fine. I see in your mapStateToProps that you access the rooms by state.rooms.rooms. Is this because you are using combineReducers? Sorry for asking but could you maybe show how you initialize the redux store?

Comment: @NielsLadekarl sorry it took so long. I have updated the original question with the reducer initialisation and the store

Comment: So after a bit more debugging, I returned the data from the API as all of the rooms. Setting this as the rooms seemed to actually update the rooms on the main screen. The only difference I could tell was that when the room I created got pushed to the array some of the keys were in a different order. Would this affect it?